# CSS3 Dropdown Menu hover different size

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

The hover state for the sub menu is 30px wider to the right side than intended.  If I change the padding it affects everything and not just the hover state.  I've been wracking my brains at this for hours so I am hoping for a few set of eyes to hopefully figure out what I am missing.

Here is the HTML:

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta harset="utf-8">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/drop.css">

    <title>CSS3 Pricing Tables</title>

</head>

<body>
<nav id="nav" role="navigation">
    <a href="#nav" title="Show navigation">Show navigation</a>
    <a href="#" title="Hide navigation">Hide navigation</a>
        <ul class="menu" id="clearfix">
            <li id="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Products</a>

                <ul>

                    <li><a href="#" class="infinity">NeuroSolutions Infinity</a>
                    <li><a href="#" class="ns">NeuroSolutions</a>
                    <li><a href="#" class="ns4ml">NeuroSolutions for MATLAB</a>
                    <li><a href="#" class="csw">Custom Solution Wizard</a>

                </ul>


            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Custom Services</a> </li>

            <li><a href="#">Customers</a>

                <ul>

                    <li><a href="#" class="case-studies">Case Studies</a>
                    <li><a href="#" class="testimonials">Testimonials</a>

                </ul>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Support</a>

                <ul>

                    <li><a href="#" class="app">Documentation</a>
                    <li><a href="#" class="website">Intro to Neural Networks</a>
                    <li><a href="#" class="website">Maintenance</a>
                    <li><a href="#" class="website">Newsletter Archive</a>
                    <li><a href="#" class="website">Video Library</a>

                </ul>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Order</a></li>
        </ul>
</nav>

</body>

</html>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
#clearfix:after {
    visibility: hidden; 
    display: block; 
    font-size: 0; 
    content: " "; 
    clear: both; 
    eight: 0; 
}

* html #clearfix { 
    zoom: 1; 
}

*:first-child+html .clearfix { 
    zoom: 1; 
}

/* Reset */

.menu, .menu ul, .menu li, .menu a {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
}

#nav {
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #4f4f4f;

    background: linear-gradient(top, #4f4f4f 0%, #343434 100%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4f4f4f 0%, #343434 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4f4f4f 0%, #343434 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #4f4f4f 0%, #343434 100%);
}

.menu {
    height: 40px;
    padding-left: 3%;
    width: auto;
    background-color: #4C4E5A;
    margin: 0;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;

    background: linear-gradient(top, #4f4f4f 0%, #343434 100%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4f4f4f 0%, #343434 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4f4f4f 0%, #343434 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #4f4f4f 0%, #343434 100%);

}

#nav > a {
    display: none;
}

#nav li {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
#nav li a            {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 85%;
    padding: 0 15px;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 40px;
}

#nav li:first-child a { border-left: none; }
#nav li:last-child a { border-left: none; }
#nav li:hover > a { background-color: #4685d2; color: #FFF; }

#nav li a:active             {
    background-color: #4685d2 !important;
}

/* first level */
#nav > ul {
    height: 100%;
}

#nav > ul > li {
    height:100%;
    float: left;
}

#nav > ul > li > a {
    height:100%;
    text-align: center;
}

/* second level */
.menu ul {
    position: absolute;
    width: 250px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    background: #343434;

    transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
    -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
    -ms-transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
}

.menu li:hover > ul {
    opacity: 1;
}

.menu ul li {
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
}

.menu li:hover > ul li {
    height: auto;
    overflow: visible;
}

.menu ul li a {
    width: 250px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    border: none;
}

.menu ul li:first-child a { border: none; }

#nav li:hover ul {
    display:block;
    width: 250px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}



@media only screen and ( max-width:62.5em ) /* 1000 */ {
    #nav         {
        width:100%;
        position:static;
        margin:0;
    }
}
@media only screen and ( max-width:40em ) /* 640 */ {
    html         {
        font-size:75%;
    /* 12 */
    }
    #nav         {
        position:relative;
        top:auto;
        left: auto;
    }
    #nav>a           {
        width:3.125em;/* 50 */
        height:3.125em;/* 50 */
        text-align:left;
        text-indent:-9999px;
        background-color:#e15a1f;
        position:relative;
    }
    #nav>a:before,              #nav>a:after                 {
        position:absolute;
        border:2px solid #fff;
        top:35%;
        left:25%;
        right:25%;
        content:'';
    }
    #nav>a:after                 {
        top:60%;
    }
    #nav:not(:target )>a:first-of-type,         #nav:target>a:last-of-type           {
        display: block;
    }
    /* first level */
    #nav>ul      {
        height:auto;
        display:none;
        position:absolute;
        left:0;
        right:0;
    }
    #nav:target>ul           {
        display:block;
    }
    #nav>ul>li           {
        width:100%;
        float:none;
    }
    #nav>ul>li>a                 {
        height:auto;
        text-align:left;
        padding:0 0.833em;
    /* 20 (24) */
    }
    #nav>ul>li:not(:last-child )>a                   {
        border-right:none;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #cc470d;
    }
    /* second level */
    #nav li ul           {
        position:static;
        padding:1.25em;/* 20 */
        padding-top:0;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
menu li ul li a:hover {
width: 220px;
}
```

Add the above class to CSS.Hope the above code works

Answer (score 0):

What is your intention with:

```
 #nav li ul           {
    position:static;
    padding:1.25em;/* 20 */
    padding-top:0;
}
```

I removed the 'padding:1.25em' and it looks good: http://jsfiddle.net/b3fhv/1/

Comment: That is for the menu to collapse into a mobile friendly dropdown menu.  That part of the code has not been finalized as I am trying to work out the desktop code first.

Comment: oh wow I didnt even notice that the site is responsive-designed. I just saw the mobile version. My answer does not make sense now